# How do I seperate a specific row from my data as a new column in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, data-cleaning

I have data in the form:

| District |
| --- |
| District A |
| District B |
| District C |
| State |
| District D |
| District E |
| State |

I need it in the form:

| District | State |
| --- | --- |
| A | State 1 |
| B | State 1 |
| C | State 1 |
| D | State 2 |
| E | State 2 |

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(State=str_c('State', cumsum(lag(District=='State', default = T))),
         District = str_remove(District, 'District ')) %>%
  filter(District != 'State')

  District  State
1        A State1
2        B State1
3        C State1
4        D State2
5        E State2
```